# how to change Hive dynamic partition default value

Tags: hive, impala

As default value of hive dynamic partition is 100 per node and in my case the value of dynamic partition is greater than 100 that's why my job got failed So can anybody suggest what is the best way to overcome this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set these desired properties just before dynamic partition:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
```

I hope this will help you!!!

Comment: I have set 1000, you can set the value according to your requirement

Comment: Thanks for your comment !!